# Create a sort of navigation logic within an application: how to?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, view

I have a number of view controllers that I want to navigate; however, I need to implement an intuitive way to move to previous ones. For the button press methods in my view controller custom classes to move forward, I do something like this:

```
NextViewController *next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithId:@"NextViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:next animated;YES];
```

With this in mind, how can I return back to previous views?

Comment: Do you know about `UINavigationController`? Check [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the built in UINavigationController? You can hide the navigation bar and use custom controls to push and pop controllers as you wish

Answer (score 0):

When using modals you simply add a button that links to the action:

```
-(void)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```